# Join text files and save then split them with same name and content

Tags: vb.net, join, merge, split

I have this code which will combine the name and content of each text file in a folder, into one string

```
 Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("D:\txtfiles\")
    Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles()
    Dim fri As FileInfo

    For Each fri In fiArr
        Dim gg As Integer = 300000
        If gg > fri.Length Then

            File.AppendAllText("1.txt", "|*|" & fri.Name & "|*|", Encoding.UTF8)
            File.AppendAllText("1.txt", File.ReadAllText(fri.FullName), Encoding.UTF8) 'The text file will be created if it does not already exist  

        End If
    Next fri
```

now i need to split them again, to save each text file with it's name and content
the splitter must be "|*|"

Comment: the current output is : |*|1.txt|*|txtfile1|*|2.txt|*|txtfile2|*|3.txt|*|txtfile3|*|4.txt|*|txtfile4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub CreateFiles(dest As String, s As String)
    Dim a = s.Split("|*|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For i As Integer = 0 To a.Count() - 2 Step 2
        File.WriteAllText(dest & a(i), a(i + 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

`dest` Is the directory in which you want the files to be saved to and
`s` is the contents of the file your code creates

Note! Don't forget to add a backslash to the string `dest`

Comment: it's not working :/ and im using 2.0 framework "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Comment: @user2618553 That really doesn't tell me a lot. What's the error?

Comment: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: @user2618553 Glad i helped :)

Comment: For arrays you should check `a.Length` rather than `a.Count()`. Otherwise a nice answer! :)